# Chaining two css animation in the same element is not working. Only the last one plays

Tags: html, css, animation

I´m trying to chain/merge two css animations. When the first ends, the second must starts. In the beginning I was doing it adjusting the timing and merging the animations classes with the transformations. Now I read that is possible to chain different animations, but although I´m trying to do it, it's not working. Only the last animation is playing.

If you want to see how it´s working now (before you give me any clue or help) look at coronafuneral.com. It is the "Contactar" text at the right part of the screen.

```css
.animacion_telefono {
  /* this is the class I attach to the anchor <a> text to animate */
  animation-delay: 0s, 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s, 3s;
  animation-duration: 1s, 3s;
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomInLeft, zoomOutDown;
  animation-name: zoomInLeft, zoomOutDown;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0);
    transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes zoomInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0);
    transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomOutDown {
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
    transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(0, 2000px, 0);
    transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(0, 2000px, 0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes zoomOutDown {
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
    transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(0, 2000px, 0);
    transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(0, 2000px, 0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-link" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: red;">
  <a style="display:block;" class="animacion_telefono" href="http://coronafuneral.com/contactanos" title="Contact us">Contact us</a>
</div>
```

This is the zoomOutDown animation, the only one that plays:

```
@-webkit-keyframes zoomOutDown {
    40% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
        transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(0, 2000px, 0);
        transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(0, 2000px, 0);
        -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
        transform-origin: center bottom;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
    }
}
@keyframes zoomOutDown {
    40% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
        transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(0, 2000px, 0);
        transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(0, 2000px, 0);
        -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
        transform-origin: center bottom;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
    }
}
```

And this is the CSS animation that is not working at all:

```
@-webkit-keyframes zoomInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0);
        transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
        transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
    }
}
@keyframes zoomInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0);
        transform: scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
        transform: scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
    }
}
```

I noticed that if I change the order of the animations in animation-name: zoomInLeft, zoomOutDown; then the animation that plays is zoomInLeft instead.

What I´m doing wrong? I can't see the point.
Thanks in advance

EDIT: this is the fiddle, this is how it works now, just playing the last animation

https://jsfiddle.net/7b5o2skb/

Comment: Provide whole code with html and try to embed in code snippet

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle replicating the problem?

Comment: Thanks @Frits for your response, this is the fiddle. I'll edit now to add it to the first post: https://jsfiddle.net/7b5o2skb/

Comment: Thanks @eirenaios for your response. I attached the fiddle

Comment: see my answer below. let me know if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 animations of the same type ( scale in your case ) can't be assigned to the same element because one will overwrite the other

you could wrap the `a` in a `p` and assign one animation to `a` and one to `p`

**see here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/7b5o2skb/1/)**

HTML :

```
<p class="animateme">
    <a style="display:block;" class="animacion_telefono" href="http://coronafuneral.com/contactanos" title="Contact us">Contact us</a>
</p>
```

CSS :

```
p.animateme {
animation-delay:  1.5s;
-webkit-animation-delay:  1.5s;  

-webkit-animation-duration:  3s;
animation-duration:  3s;

-webkit-animation-name:  zoomOutDown;
animation-name:  zoomOutDown;

-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;

animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;

}
```

but making animations go on forever ( infinite ) i don't think you can only with css. you have to tell one animation to start after the other over and over again. now, with css , it only works the first time because the first animation starts immediately after it finished its animation, and the second animation isn't finished yet. so they will animate the elements in the same time ( except the first time they animate )

this can be done with jq but not css